# How to reduce file size in THREE.js GLTF exports

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, filesize, gltf

I'm building a Mancala game in THREE.js, using fairly simple shapes and physics for a more visceral experience than the usual overhead 2D view. Might be overkill, but that's life :)

I've managed to build a board I like, but since it involves a modest amount of code and cycles to assemble, I figured I should build it separately and export that object as a GLTF or GLB file to load into the client-facing version. The trouble is, the [`GLTFExporter`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/exporters/GLTFExporter) function is spitting out files of 3 or 4MB, even in binary, for what is not a hugely complex shape. (OBJ is even worse.) **My question is: What in a THREE.js object can cause exports files to grow so quickly, and what can one sacrifice for the greatest reduction in size?**

**Background:**

I want the board to have rounded edges on the perimeter and inside the bins, like a normal board you can [buy online](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01JBFOTDI):

[image]

After many experiments with [ThreeCSG](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG/blob/master/examples.html), I found it was much easier to use [Paul West's elegant RoundEdgeBox (2.0)](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/round-edged-box-2/1448) for the outer frame, cutting out the top and bottom edges, then including the dividers between the bins and larger basins with simple BoxGeometries:

[image]

That object exports to a very manageable 170Kb or so in GLTF format.

To round the inside of the cavities, I used `ExtrudeGeometry` to make a PI/2 arc that is merged into the inside of the bins:

```
    // length is the height, size is the thickness
    let makeBorder = function(length, radius, size) {
        extrudeSettings.depth = length;
        let shape = new THREE.Shape();
        shape.moveTo(radius + size, 0 );
        shape.arc(-radius - size, 0, radius + size, 0, Math.PI / 2, false)
        shape.lineTo( 0, radius );
        shape.arc(0, -radius, radius, Math.PI / 2, 0, true)
        shape.lineTo( radius + size, 0 );

        let geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
        geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        return geometry;
    }
```

Merging eight of these quarter-arcs to the size of the bottom and vertical edges of the bins, you get a really nice curvature:

[image]

What is NOT nice is that it imposes several MB of information to the GLTF and GLB files. I'm fairly sure I did all the obvious things right:

- I exported the object, not the entire scene
- I brought down the number
  of segments in the arcs to a few as possible before the curves look
  too choppy
- I used the simplest possible materials (no images)

Just eyeballing the JSON version of the export (GLTF), I see a few things at the end that I didn't ask for, like `pbrMetallicRoughness` under `materials:`

```
"materials": [
{
  "pbrMetallicRoughness": {
    "baseColorFactor": [
      0.6784313725490196,
      0.8470588235294118,
      0.9019607843137255,
      1
    ],
    "metallicFactor": 0.5,
    "roughnessFactor": 0.5
  }
}
]
```

But I don't think this is adding much. There are four `BufferViews`, all of substantial size. Is that normal and necessary?

```
"bufferViews": [
{
  "buffer": 0,
  "byteOffset": 0,
  "byteLength": 35712,
  "target": 34962,
  "byteStride": 12
},
{
  "buffer": 0,
  "byteOffset": 35712,
  "byteLength": 35712,
  "target": 34962,
  "byteStride": 12
},
{
  "buffer": 0,
  "byteOffset": 71424,
  "byteLength": 35712,
  "target": 34962,
  "byteStride": 12
},
{
  "buffer": 0,
  "byteOffset": 107136,
  "byteLength": 23808,
  "target": 34962,
  "byteStride": 8
}
]
```

Right now, my plan of attack is to reduce the output to one basin and one bin, then clone and stitch them together on the client. This isn't difficult, but I wish it wasn't necessary. Given that this shape replicates the same subshapes many times, is there no way to make a concise GLTF?

Comment: I'm guessing the size likely comes from the finely-rounded corners, producing a ton of vertex data.  Can you reduce the resolution there?  Also, can you share a complete sample glTF + bin file for us to examine?

Comment: Don't worry about the `pbrMetallicRoughness` thing, that's just defining the color of the material (in linear space, not sRGB).  It's a few bytes of JSON but there's no associated binary data for that.

Comment: You could cut down your filesize in half by only exporting half the board! Since it's symmetrical, you can duplicate the board on the client-side, and rotate it 180 in the y-axis, so it looks like two pieces like in the screenshot you shared.

Comment: Great point! In fact, if I split the basins and bins, I only need one of each. Thanks!

Comment: You can also compress the model using https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-pipeline/. There's an extra section in the three.js docs about loading compressed glTF models. This reduces file size significantly, but not the number of vertices.